# :first-letter text-decoration browser support

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm having an issue where the `text-decoration` attribute isn't working with the `first-letter` specification.

In this example the purpose of the code is to style the first letter of each `<div class="content">` block.

```
div.content:first-letter {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #bd00df;
}
```

The first letter of each `<div class="content">`block does turn purple, but it doesn't get underlined.
How do I get it to underline in a simple and productive way?

Comment: it might not be properly supported by the browser you're using.

Comment: You think Google Chrome wouldn't support it?

Comment: Chrome isn't perfect.

Comment: You have no idea. There are an *astounding* number of CSS1/CSS2 features Google Chrome doesn't implement correctly. None of this is CSS3, despite the tags you've given your question. This is fundamental CSS1 stuff.

Comment: Oh wow it does work on IE9, but not Chrome...

Comment: I re-installed Chrome out of curiosity, it didn't say I had an update before, but something changed and the border-bottom now works.

Comment: What version is now installed?

Comment: Version 37.0.2062.102 m

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is a bug** present in Chrome from version 36+. The `text-decoration` does not render when set with `:first-letter`.

Chrome has an interesting history of rendering differences for `text-decoration: underline` when compared to other browsers.

These examples have the first letter set at `font-size: 10em;`. I have obtained the screenshots with [crossbrowsertesting.com](http://crossbrowsertesting.com).

You can view the full results on Chrome for OSX [here](http://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/public/i4fc93605bfe96a0/screenshots/z4427d589b682267f092) and Windows 7 [here](http://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/public/i4fc93605bfe96a0/screenshots/z6545678a98971ab0523)

You can view the jsfiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8gz74y1m/2/show/)

## **Firefox is consistent**

For comparison, Firefox has [these consistent results, tested from Version 7](http://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/public/i4fc93605bfe96a0/screenshots/zffb0afc5eabe89eaca5):

[image: Firefox screenshot]

## **Internet Explorer**

[Even IE is more consistent.](http://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/public/i4fc93605bfe96a0/screenshots/z4546b1f464ae18a3883?size=small&type=windowed)

IE 6 - 7                                             IE8+

[image: Screenshot IE 6 - 7]         [image: Screenshot IE8+]

## **Chrome is different**

These are taken from Chrome running on Mac OS 10.9 and Windows 7 64bit

**Chrome Version 19 - Version 31**

Single pixel underline

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Chrome Version 32 - Version 33**

The underline is enlarged

[image: Screenshot 2]

**Chrome Version 34 - Version 35**

Windows 7 64bit                                    Mac OSX

[image: Screenshot 2] [image: Screenshot 3]

**Chrome Version 36+**

Bug, no underline when set with `:first-letter`.

[image: Screenshot 4]

Comment: To be fair, the spec doesn't define exactly how a browser should paint text decorations, or whether or not it should scale with the text, but I would expect there to be some sort of consistency. Then again, this *is* Chrome we're talking about...

Comment: 34 - 35 seems to have the best underline for the font-size. It seems like an oversight to not have a definition size in the spec.

Comment: The spec says that UAs *may* scale text decorations with the text, but since font rendering is so highly dependent on the rendering algorithm and the typeface (e.g. some faces are designed to have really tiny glyphs), I don't think you *could* define this very precisely at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-bottom` instead:

```
div.content:first-letter {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    color: #bd00df;
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcdvqfbo/)

Comment: That does do the trick but I want to see if there's a way to make the text-decoration attribute work.

Comment: Turns out the `underline` value for `text-decoration` when used on the first letter isn't supported by Chrome, so this is the closest we can get.

Comment: There are ways to make it work with `underline` in Chrome too but it involves too much pain and in my case `border-bottom` does the job.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It is in fact working fine in chrome. This would be a browser support issue you are experiencing

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/3pg23vck/

```
div.content:first-letter {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #bd00df;
}
```

Chome Mac Version 30.0.1599.101 tested

Comment: I see no underline in `Chrome 37.0.2062.102 (64-bit)`.

Comment: I see the underline in Firefox (v31), not in Chrome Version 37.0.2062.94 (64-bit) on Linux.

Comment: [On the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) it says that `text-decoration` should be supported.

Comment: @haim770 it's Working on some browsers and not on others. This is definitely a browser issue. You saying it doesn't work on a single browser you are using, proves nothing. Try it on every browser on your machine and then constructively report accordingly.

Comment: I just tried. It's working in IE11 but not in chrome.

Comment: @StevenPHP, That's the reason the OP is asking the question, because it doesn't work for his Browser too. Answering with 'It does work for me' doesn't help.

Comment: @StevenPHP: It beats you singling him out and not reporting any findings yourself. FTR, I can confirm haim770's findings on my own PC.

Comment: Did I find a bug then?

Comment: @Seth Taddiken: Yes, and a particularly annoying kind at that: a regression, i.e. something that used to work as intended but is now broken. Chrome is notorious for that.